# Angular interceptor executed before http request

Tags: angular, http, jwt, mean-stack, angular-http-interceptors

I'm working with a MEAN app and I'm having problems with the token interceptor. It is supposed to apply the headers after an user is logged in with this code:

```
 intercept(request: HttpRequest<unknown>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<unknown>> {
    const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
    let req = request;
    if (token) {
      req = request.clone({
        setHeaders: {
          authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
        }
      });
    }
 }
```

However, I debugged the code and it is being executed before the login calls the api (so there's no login, no token, no user data, etc.). Thus it's useless, because I need the token in order to set the headers as the code shows.

Comment: You have to `return` something meaningful in order for it to work https://angular.io/guide/http#intercepting-requests-and-responses

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can combine it with a pipe and tap (or any other  RxJs operators) to operate on a response call before it gets to your service.

[logging-request-and-response-pairs](https://angular.io/guide/http#logging-request-and-response-pairs)

```
intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler) {
       // change req here before being send
           
        return next.handle(req)
          .pipe(
            tap(
              // to access data, or use map to manipulate it.
            )
          );
```